# Where can I find a clear overview of the grothendieck construction?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, category-theory, algebraic-stacks, grothendieck-construction

I have seen the grothendieck construction referenced in the literature several times, but never have found a good clean overview of how it works. How can I go from a stack which is a category fibered in groupoids over a site, let's say $(Sch/S)_{et}$, to a groupoid in $(Sch/S)$, and then back? For example, consider the quotient stack associated to the ramified etale cover
$$
\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^5 - y)) \to \text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[y])
$$
with isotropy group $\mathbb{Z}/5$ at the origin.

Comment: You just mean a groupoid in sheaves on $Sch/S$, no? As phrased it seems you're looking for this groupoid to be representable.

Comment: No, category fibered in groupoids

Comment: Yes, you started with a category fibered in groupoid, but I was asking for clarification on the other side of the correspondence. You shouldn't be expecting to get a groupoid object in the category of schemes.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I should get a groupoid of algebraic spaces, and I should consider those as sheaves on the etale site.